# How to Log All mysql queries into log file?

Tags: mysql, log

I am using Mysql 5.6.12 under Wamp server environment. Now I want to log All queries into ".log" file, the queries which are running by PHP or from PHPMyAdmin, I want to log them...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
[mysqld]
# Set Slow Query Log
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /usr/log/slowquery.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

#Set General Log
general_log = on
general_log_file=/usr/log/general.log
```

Note that enabling `general_log` on a production server has overhead you should avoid it. You can check problematic queries from `slow log`.

Comment: For me, I had to use "general_log = 1" instead of "general_log = on".

Comment: Worked on Wamp Server, using mysql 5.6.7. The only thing I had to change were the paths to tje files, in my case, C:\wamp\logs\mysql_query.log .

Comment: Why all these config values? Just `general_log` and `general_log_file` is enough.

Answer (score 14):

Since this is the type of thing you probably only want to do temporarily, it may be useful to do this from the shell instead of via the config file:

```
> set global general_log_file = "/var/log/mysql/queries.log";
> set global general_log = "ON";
[wait some time, hit some pages, whatever]
> set global general_log = "OFF";
```

Comment: Note, that you need root privileges in the DB for these instructions, which is not a surprise.

Answer (score 7):

Put these two lines in my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]

general_log     = on
general_log_file=/users/ugrad/linehanp/mydb/logfile.txt
```

This will log **all** queries to the server, from any source, not just PHP/PHPMyAdmin.

Be careful though - enabling the general log can place a heavy load on your server. To be used sparingly for short periods/debugging only.

The documentation is available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html). Fro there:

> To disable or enable the general query log or change the log file name
>   at runtime, use the global general_log and general_log_file system
>   variables. Set general_log to 0 (or OFF) to disable the log or to 1
>   (or ON) to enable it. Set general_log_file to specify the name of the
>   log file.

So,

```
general_log     = on
```

and

```
general_log     = 1
```

are synonyms!

Comment: For me, I had to use "general_log = 1" instead of "general_log = on".

Comment: @GuyPaddock what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Is this the `.my.cnf` file in a user's home directory? Or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` , which on my system is a symlink to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` ?

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu), the correct file to edit was `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`