# MySQL : How to know if Trigger was fired

Tags: mysql, trigger

Someone can help me please , I want to log error about triggers in MySQL 5.5
I'll like to know if it's possible to know if a trigger was'nt fired ?

Comment: When the trigger was created successfully, you can safely assume that it's fired when the appropriate DML statement is executed.

Comment: Write something in a temporary table if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the hard way by enabling MySQL logging (all SQL queries will be logged). I'm doing it when I'm trying to debug & understand complex code base with big amount of SQL queries, with SQL procedures, events & triggers. It's ugly, but it works.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213374189-How-to-enable-MySQL-logging-

[How to Log All mysql queries into log file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62129/how-to-log-all-mysql-queries-into-log-file)

```
Debian-based systems:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
# Set Slow Query Log
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

# Set General Log
general_log = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-general.log
```